# Change views of records based on Filter criteria in crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I want to shift a record automatically based on filter criteria from Active view to a custom view "Processed". The criteria is shift record from `Active` to `Processed` when `field contains data`. Although this is working, the record still shows in `Active`.

I simply cannot find the reason why? Maybe its very simple too. Help?

Comment: What you are describing sounds like a workflow rather than a view. A view does not "shift" anything. I think you need to customize the view to filter on the field that contains `Active` and `Processed` field

Comment: and this is happening only in one particular entity.

Comment: @Eccountable, This is now a worklfow I am talking about. You can add filter criteria to views. `Active` and `Processed` are views of an entity.

Comment: So I am guessing then that when you say "automatically" you really mean that you want the view for one user to update the moment the workflow updates the record from Active to Processed - correct?

Comment: No...when you add a filter criteria to view related to an entity, and when that criteria is fulfilled the record changes the view...right now although this is happening, the record shows it self in both views rather than to which its filter criteria has been fulfilled.

Comment: I think you also need to add the critera to say when `field does not contain data` to your active view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the views are mutually exclusive, and one of them is using the criteria `field contains data`, then the other view must use `field does not contain data` in order for your data to appear in the correct place.